# laravel 5 issue with slashes in query

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and I am facing issues with query when I have slashes(forward or backward)

publications table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `publications` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `firm` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `sector_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_from` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_to` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `region_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `file_name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `category_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `sub_category_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `manually_verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO `publications` (`id`, `user_id`, `title`, `type`, `company`, `author`, `firm`, `address`, `sector_id`, `date_from`, `date_to`, `region_id`, `file_name`, `created_at`, `created_by`, `updated_at`, `updated_by`, `is_active`, `category_id`, `sub_category_id`, `manually_verified`) VALUES
(3, 7, 'test publication 3', 'test 1', 'test 1', 'test author 1', 'test 1', 'test3', 1, '2015-06-09 11:54:18', '2015-06-29 18:30:00', 0, 'files/testing/testing.pdf', '2015-06-06 05:58:10', 7, '2015-06-13 03:31:45', 7, 0, 4, 1, 0),
(4, 7, 'test publication 4', 'test 2', 'test 2', 'test author 2', 'test 2', 'test2', 1, '2015-06-09 11:54:23', '2015-06-29 18:30:00', 0, 'test1.pdf', '2015-06-06 05:58:10', 7, '2015-06-05 23:58:10', 7, 1, 4, 1, 0),
(5, 7, 'test 5', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 1, '2015-06-09 11:54:09', '2015-06-29 18:30:00', 0, 'files/Bugzilla-uermanual.pdf', '2015-06-06 05:58:10', 7, '2015-06-13 03:19:21', 7, 0, 4, 1, 1);
```

**Laravel 5**

```
$arr = array( 'file_paths' => Array ( 'files/testing/testing.pdf', 'files/Bugzilla-uermanual.pdf' ) );
Query
    $this->publications
        ->where(['category_id'=>$search_cat_id])
        ->where(function ($query) use ($arr){
                foreach ($arr['file_paths'] as $key=>$value){
                    $query->orWhere('file_name', DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($value));
                }    
            })  
        ->get();
    print_r($publications_records);
```

I don't get any result. If I execute the query which was generated by laravel it is getting executed.

Below is the query generated by Laravel and if I execute this in MySQL I get results.

```
select * from `publications` 
where (`category_id` = 4) and 
(`file_name` = 'files/testing/testing.pdf' 
    or `file_name` = 'files/Bugzilla-uermanual.pdf') 
order by `id` desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr = ['files/testing/testing.pdf', 'files/Bugzilla-uermanual.pdf']; 
$publications_records = $this->publications()
    ->where('category_id', $search_cat_id)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($arr){ 
        foreach ($arr as $value){
            $query->orWhere('file_name', $value);
        }
    })
    ->get();
dd($publications_records, DB:getQueryLog());
```

If the above code doesnt work. Please edit your question and paste the output